# Comparing two panda dataframes and writing new dataframes if a row value is common between both dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

First of all I am going to explain the whole problem and if there is a better way to do this without pandas please say. I have just attempted a bunch of ways and I feel like pandas is likely the best way to go.

I have two text files. Each text file looks something like the following:

```
Sometextinbothfiles    UniqueText    SomeTextThatCouldbeCommon    Unique Text
```

There are more columns with UniqueText in but this gives a basic idea of the layout. There is also some header info but this is easy to remove by ignoring the first 22 lines in pandas.The column with the SomeTextThatCouldbeCommon is always in the same place and it is this that I want to look at. It is a filename.

Currently I am just pulling in each text file and seperating them in pandas using

```
Data = open("data.star", "r")
Datapd = pd.read_csv(Data, sep=r"\s+", skiprows=range(0,23), header=None)
```

So I want to compare the SomeTextThatCouldbeCommon on each line of the text file to the same SomeTextThatCouldbeCommon on EVERY line of the other text file. If there is a match I then want to write out that whole line to a new dataframe/textfile/array. I then want to do the same in reverse. So in the end I have two files that refer to the same files but have the unique data present in each file about that data.

I hope I have explained this ok. Please help I am struggling to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches? Please provide example of input of both `DataFrames` as well as expected output. Also note that your `Data` variable is redundant as `pd.read_csv()` will open (and close) the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi mate here you could find simple example for solving your problem, I hope is gonna work for you:

two example data-frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
"Date" : [2013-11-24, 2013-11-24, 2013-11-24, 2013-11-24],
"Fruit" : ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Celery'], 
"Num" : [22.1, 8.6, 7.6, 10.2],
"Color" : ['Yellow', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Green']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
"Date" : [2013-11-25, 2013-11-24, 2013-11-24, 2018-11-24],
"Fruit" : ['Banana', 'Cherry', 'Mango', 'Celery'], 
"Num" : [22.1, 8.6, 7.6, 10.2],
"Color" : ['Yellow', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Green']
})

mask = (df1 == df2)
df1.where(mask)
```

where there is a match you have result otherwise you should receive "NaN" values.

Comment: That looks for differences whereas I am looking for matches. I have already tried using that question to make it work in reverse with no luck.

Comment: just change the equality into difference by changing == to != ->  
`mask = (df1 != df2)`